# Python (how do i make text appear slower in the python shell)

Tags: python, text

I am trying to code a game but I am  stuck on trying to make print come up slower in the python shell I appreciate all help here is the code so far

```
print ("welcome to the music guessing game")
print (" begin?")

print (" first of all lets go through the rules")

print (" You have three 3 lives to answer each song in this game")
print (" If you get it on the first turn you gain 3 points")
print (" if you get it on the second try you gain 1 point")
print ( " If you get it wrong again you lose one life and it proceeds to the next question")
print (" One major rule have fun while playing")


username=input (" what is your username")
print ("Is this your name ?",username)

password=input (" Enter your password please")
print (" password gained",password)

print ("Checking the data files")
print ("10%")
print ("20%")
print ("30%")
print ("40%")
print ("50%")
print ("60%")
print ("70%")
print ("80%")
print ("90%")
print  ("100%")
print (" check complete")

import random
def fifty_fifty():
        "return 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 5 with 50% chance each"
        return random.randrange

print (" High Scores!!!!!")

print ("[DEV]LB123 score 1200")
print (" PewDiePie score 420")
print (" Callmekevin score 68")
print ("[BOT] Tseries score 0")



option=input ("would you like to play")
print ("would you like to play "+ option +"?")
```

I gained this information for the inputs from https://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html

```
print (" okay then lets begin ")



print (" Round One " )


print (" Lets begin " )

print ("3")
print ("2")
print ("1")



print (" 'N_ Te_rs L_ft _o _r_'")

if input (" No Tears Left To Cry")
 print ("3 points")

elif input (" no answer")
print (" 1 life gone 2 remain")
```

So the question is, how do i make text appear slower in the python shell? Thank you

Comment: use `time.sleep(sec)` after each print

Comment: it worked thank you so much couldn't find a site that told me any info on this

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [sleep](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-time-sleep-pause-wait-sleep-stop-your-code/) in your code.

Also, welcome to SO! In the future, please format your code properly so that it'll appear correctly. You can see various ways on [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

```
import time 
seconds_for_sleep = 4
name = str(input("Username"))
time.sleep(int(seconds_for_sleep))
print("See! This fuction waited", seconds_for_sleep," seconds!`enter code here`)
```